# MySQL UPDATE Hangs with No Error

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Here is a query I'm trying to run:

```
UPDATE tblmatters SET 
subMatterName = null, 
matterName = 'Travelers v. Allstate', 
dateOpen = '2011-04-13', 
dateClosed = null, 
orgAttorney_fk = 129, 
billingAttorney_fk = 129, 
responsibleAttorney_fk = 129, 
typeOfLawCode_fk = 050, 
updatedBy = 'RAINMAKR', 
updatedOn = NOW() 
WHERE parentID = 275 AND matterID = '00968'
```

Every time I try to execute, it just hangs in a state that looks like its attempting to run the query. I get no error, no stop, it will just continue on indefinitely. I've left it for over an hour and it was still sitting there, trying to execute.

Any ideas on what this problem is?? Please let me know if you need more info!

**EDIT**

Here is the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblmatters`:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblmatters` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parentID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `matterID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `subMatterID` varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000',
  `matterName` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `akaMatterName` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subMatterName` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orgAttorney_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billingAttorney_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `associateAttorney_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `responsibleAttorney_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `typeOfLawCode_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `departmentCode_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateOpen` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateClosed` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateReview` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedBy` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `updatedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniqueCompositeKey` (`parentID`,`matterID`,`subMatterID`),
  KEY `parentID` (`parentID`),
  KEY `orgAttorney` (`orgAttorney_fk`),
  KEY `billingAttorney` (`billingAttorney_fk`),
  KEY `associateAttorney` (`associateAttorney_fk`),
  KEY `responsibleAttorney` (`responsibleAttorney_fk`),
  KEY `typeOfLawCode` (`typeOfLawCode_fk`),
  KEY `departmentCode` (`departmentCode_fk`),
  CONSTRAINT `tblmatters_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parentID`) REFERENCES `tblclients` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tblmatters_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`orgAttorney_fk`) REFERENCES `tblrequesters` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tblmatters_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`billingAttorney_fk`) REFERENCES `tblrequesters` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tblmatters_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`associateAttorney_fk`) REFERENCES `tblrequesters` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tblmatters_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`responsibleAttorney_fk`) REFERENCES `tblrequesters` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tblmatters_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`typeOfLawCode_fk`) REFERENCES `tbltypeoflaw` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tblmatters_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`departmentCode_fk`) REFERENCES `tbldepartments` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=68909 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is the INNODB Status output:

```
InnoDB      
=====================================
131014 15:18:38 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 60 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 916 1_second, 915 sleeps, 91 10_second, 6 background, 6 flush
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 937
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 157, signal count 164
Mutex spin waits 40, rounds 562, OS waits 8
RW-shared spins 253, rounds 5347, OS waits 128
RW-excl spins 3, rounds 652, OS waits 21
Spin rounds per wait: 14.05 mutex, 21.13 RW-shared, 217.33 RW-excl
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 20042
Purge done for trx's n:o < 20024 undo n:o < 0
History list length 2031
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 29, OS thread handle 0xdc8, query id 7576476 localhost 127.0.0.1 root
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
---TRANSACTION 20041, ACTIVE 2 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 2, OS thread handle 0x106c, query id 7556956 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Updating
UPDATE tblmatters SET 
subMatterName = null, 
matterName = 'Travelers v. Allstate', 
dateOpen = '2011-04-13', 
dateClosed = null, 
orgAttorney_fk = 129, 
billingAttorney_fk = 129, 
responsibleAttorney_fk = 129, 
typeOfLawCode_fk = 050, 
updatedBy = 'RAINMAKR', 
updatedOn = NOW() 
WHERE 
parentID = 275
AND 
matterID = '00968'
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 2 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 5806 n bits 464 index `uniqueCompositeKey` of table `ft_test`.`tblmatters` trx id 20041 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 391 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000113; asc     ;;
 1: len 5; hex 3030393638; asc 00968;;
 2: len 7; hex 30303030303030; asc 0000000;;
 3: len 4; hex 8000ff27; asc    ';;

------------------
---TRANSACTION 2001E, ACTIVE 898 sec
243 lock struct(s), heap size 47544, 6342 row lock(s), undo log entries 4922
MySQL thread id 10, OS thread handle 0x11f8, query id 7576479 localhost 127.0.0.1 root statistics
SELECT id FROM tblfolders WHERE parentID = 66633 AND folderNo = '1'
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 2001F, sees < 2001F
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: wait Windows aio (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: wait Windows aio (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
3230 OS file reads, 4063 OS file writes, 1305 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 2.72 writes/s, 1.42 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 1 merges
merged operations:
 insert 1, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 276707, node heap has 71 buffer(s)
8984.30 hash searches/s, 37.93 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 297152094
Log flushed up to   297152094
Last checkpoint at  297152094
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
1003 log i/o's done, 1.12 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 137363456; in additional pool allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 197452
Buffer pool size   8192
Free buffers       5020
Database pages     3099
Old database pages 1163
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 3091, created 8, written 2924
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 1.47 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 3099, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[5], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
2 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread id 4144, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 2656, updated 2270, deleted 0, read 8876597
1.43 inserts/s, 1.33 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 8987.88 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

And here is the PROCESSLIST:

```
1   root    localhost:49283 ft_test Sleep   90      
2   root    localhost:49284 ft_test Query   5   Updating    UPDATE tblmatters SET 
subMatterName = null, 
matterName = 'Travelers v. Allstate', 
dateOpen = '2011-04-13', 
dateClosed = null, 
orgAttorney_fk = 129, 
billingAttorney_fk = 129, 
responsibleAttorney_fk = 129, 
typeOfLawCode_fk = 050, 
updatedBy = 'RAINMAKR', 
updatedOn = NOW() 
WHERE 
parentID = 275
AND 
matterID = '00968'
10  root    localhost:49513 ft_test Sleep   0       
22  root    localhost:49701     Sleep   243     
24  root    localhost:49733 ft_test Sleep   68      
26  root    localhost:49735     Sleep   52      
28  root    localhost:49737 ft_test Sleep   35      
29  root    localhost:49738 ft_test Sleep   3       
30  root    localhost:49739 ft_test Sleep   33      
31  root    localhost:49740 ft_test Query   0       SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblmatters;` in the question?

Comment: You might also want to check your mysql log file. It could be blocking on connections, table locks, corrupted table, etc.

Comment: Also, are there any triggers on the table?

Comment: @ErikNedwidek there are no triggers (I hate triggers and avoid them at all costs) and I don't see anything telling in my mysql log file... very strange huh?

Comment: OK, now with the query running (and "hanging") can you run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS ;` and `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` and append the outputs in the question, too?

Comment: Can you madd the output off `Explain...` ? And did you tried another smaller update maybe on another table?

Comment: For anyone getting this in a Python application, make sure to commit the connection after updating, and if you're using a context manager, make sure you leave the scope of the `with` statement before doing anything else with the same row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out. My problem had to do with an on-going transaction that was never committing or rolling back - thus, I was just stuck while this process was going on.

Would be nice if MySQL would let you know instead of just stalling out but nevertheless, my problem has been averted.

Answer (score -1):

Your transaction will only stop if the other transaction was operating on the same row/page.
Plan your transactions well to avoid this in future.